# MySQL: select top result in a group of distinct(char_length(text_column)) records

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a group of records that look like these following notional results.  There are multiple occurrences where the number in the count column is repeated.  'count' comes from char_length(text_column). I want to grab the first record in each such grouping.  How do I do this?

I've looked at the char_length() documentation and searched for examples where this has been done, but can't find anything.

```
select distinct(char_length(text_column)), text_column from table
```

.... is as close -- which is not obviously close -- as I've been able to get to the result.

```
=======+============================
 count +      text_column
=======+============================
2139   + some text entry
-------+----------------------------
3000   + another sentence here
-------+----------------------------
3000   + more text in this sentence
-------+----------------------------
3000   + still more text here
-------+----------------------------
```

Thank you,
BW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "first" unless a column specifies the ordering.  You can, however, get a value from an *indeterminate* row by using `group by`:

```
select char_length(text_column), text_column
from table
group by char_length(text_column);
```

I'm not a big fan of using the MySQL extension to `group by` where `text_column` is allowed in the `select`, but not the `group by`.  However, because it is a long column, it might be more efficient to just let MySQL pick the value rather than using an actual aggregation function (such as `min()` or `max()`).

Comment: Such a simple approach to resolve my issue.  It works great -- much obliged.